# What is producing "Invalid option for project: true" when running 'tslint --project' on a React project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tslint

I'm trying to set up tslint to work on a small sample React/Typescript project, following a tutorial online. When I either run `yarn lint` or simply enter `tslint --project` in the terminal, I keep getting the error

> Invalid option for project: true

I've done a lot of googling, and I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

My `tslint.json` is

```
{
  "extends": [
    "tslint:recommended",
    "tslint-react",
    "tslint-config-prettier"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "ordered-imports": false,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "no-console": false,
    "jsx-no-lambda": false,
    "member-ordering": false
  }
}
```

and my `package.json`is

```
{
  "name": "something",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel ./src/index.html",
    "lint": "tslint --project",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.3",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "tslint": "^5.19.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "tslint-react": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop": "^10.0.14",
    "@emotion/core": "^10.0.16",
    "@emotion/styled": "^10.0.15",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "bulma": "^0.7.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  }
}
```

It may be I've messed up the `package.json` in converting this from the original `eslint` version, but I am lost at this point.  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `--project` needs a param, i think thats for telling it where to get your `tsconfig.json` file. Something like `tslint --project ./some/path/tsconfig.json`

Comment: @JohnRuddell -- That seemed to have worked.  But the tslint docs say 'By default, TSLint looks for a configuration file named tslint.json in the directory of the file being linted and, if not found, searches ancestor directories.', and I'm running the command in the same directory as the tslint.json file....

Comment: yea, so in other words, dont pass `--project` you're incorrectly calling it. just run `tslint`. If you do pass the project flag then give it a path as well :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell -- `tslint` by itself gives me `No files specified. Use --project to lint a project folder.`.  But `tslint --project  '.'` works

Comment: lol, like I was saying, either dont pass it (sounds like u need to from that error), or if you do pass it, use it correctly :). Looks like the tsconfig.json file is at the current directory you're running tslint off of. glad that works!

Answer (score 6):

The trick is that one needs to specify the directory where one is (ts)linting.  Thus if you're in the root of your project,

```
tslint --project '.'
```

does the trick.

Comment: Thanks , this worked .  Error message should say "cannot find project folder"  or something more helpful.

Comment: I'm getting `Invalid option for project: '.'`