# Cannot deploy Firebase Cloud function after migrating to Typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, tslint

I just followed the firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript) in order to migrate my cloud functions project to typescript and now, i Have the following error when I use : 'firebase deploy --only functions'

here is the stacktrace :

```
deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint (here is my project path)
> tslint -p tslint.json

Invalid option for project: tslint.json
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `tslint -p tslint.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/macbook/.npm/_logs/2020-12-08T17_25_16_433Z-debug.log
```

My tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "types": ["node"],
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

My package.json :

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "main": "./src/index.ts",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/tslint -p tslint.json",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.13.0",
    "googleapis": "^39.2.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typedi": "^0.8.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.10",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.7"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: I have tried almost everything that i could get on google but i'm realy getting low on idea now. I cannot move my project forward, if anybody got an idea it would be super appreciated !

Comment: Could you please add the code of your cloud functions? This to be able to replicate to se what is going on.

Comment: was able to make it work as stated in my answer. Thank you for your concern !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, I reverted all the changes, cleaned the node_module and restarted the migration again.

I left my index as .js and not .ts for the moment and it worked. At the end, here is my conf in case it could help someone in the future :

package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/tslint --project tsconfig.json && ./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.13.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.7"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "allowJs": "true"
}
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's the same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57680471/what-is-producing-invalid-option-for-project-true-when-running-tslint-proj)

Try switching to,

```
"lint": "./node_modules/.bin/tslint -p tslint.json .",
```

or replace the `.` with the path of the directory that you are linting

Comment: unfortunately it did not change anything :(